# Help removing ubuntu 12.10!

Tags: 12.10, laptop

I have Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop, no Windows.

I have my system disks and tried to do a system recovery and it won't allow me.

I've tried creating a boot disk and doing the "try ubuntu" and installing the OS uninstaller.

My laptop freezes up in this process.

Any other suggestions on how to remove ubuntu and reinstall my windows vista again?

Comment: There are no other options to install windows. If you are having a problem, ask on a windows support site.

Comment: @jamiej86 It sounds like you're saying the Ubuntu live system freezes when you attempt to install OS Uninstaller. But there are [other ways to remove Ubuntu, given in answers to that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/22949), besides using OS Uninstaller. You may alternatively prefer to remove Ubuntu's partitions manually from the *Windows* installation CD/DVD/USB (which you can do when telling Windows where to install itself). For information on how to do that, you should ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com) or somewhere else Windows is supported. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try booting into your Ubuntu Install Media.

Go through the installation process until you get to where you want to install it.

Format your hard drive(s) from there.

Profit.

Or, just boot into Recovery Mode. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: It seems to be working so far! Thank you! Why couldn't anyone else give me this answer?

Comment: @cxdy Recovery mode is still the installed Ubuntu system (with at least the root filesystem mounted), so I think removing Ubuntu's partitions in it is somewhat unlikely to succeed. (And if it did, the OS would appear to still be installed until shutdown, after which one could not then boot back into recovery mode to check to be sure partitions had been fully removed.) However, using the partition utility in Ubiquity (Ubuntu's graphical installer) as an alternative to GParted or other partitioners to remove the old system's partitions (and then quitting the installer) is an excellent idea!

Comment: Glad it's working, @jamiej86

Comment: Oh, dammit. I had forgotten about that, Eliah. Thanks though! @EliahKagan

Comment: Okay doing that didn't work all the way. I used the installer for Ubuntu to change the partitions of the Ubuntu that was already on there. Since it was the main partition I couldn't delete it and just exit out. So I made it as small as possible then exited out of the Ubuntu boot usb. Then I went back into Ubuntu and used gparted to create a new partition in fat32 for windows. I popped in the windows recovery cd and so far it's going good, no errors but I'm still on disk 1.

Comment: Okay, good. Disk 1? Shouldn't you have one disc for Windows? I mean, it's not _that_ big aha. Alright, let us know if anything goes bumpy.

Comment: Idk my computer made it on 2 disks? Idk, it's vista lol. So far so good, on disk 2 now and it's at 90%.

Comment: You should have three discs. Operating System, Drivers & Utilities and Application. All you really need is Operating System. You might need Drivers & Utilities, too.

Comment: 2 recovery disks and apparently I need to go disk hunting cause I only have 1 of 2 system disks :o

Comment: Ooh. If you can't find them, go get an ISO for a Windows version.

Comment: Just a scare, idk why I had it in a different drawer! Omg .. Crisis adverted!  Everything is still looking good. I'm hoping when it's done I can use windows partition to delete the Ubuntu partition. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just get Windows Vista DVD.
Boot into Disk (Check mobo documentation for booting into dvd).
Follow on screen instructions provided by Windows Vista installation interface.
When comes to partitioning Hard Disk - Delete all partitions and install a fresh copy of windows.

Comment: when trying to use the recovery disks, it says no partition. Is there a way i can create a partition?

Answer (score -1):

You could also use Gparted - partitioning tool ( on normal or failsafe mode ) , it's just amazing !

You could do all the operations on manual( advanced mode), with Gparted you could even create the future EXT4 partitions on which you plan to reinstall Ubuntu, you need a / partition (I'd give atleast 20 GB ) a  /HOME partition (or use the one you already have) and a SWAP partition( I would size it to 1 GB).

English being my third language I didn't noticed that you plan to dump Ubuntu :) . I had some issues with my toshiba laptop ( and the shitty i3 integrated everything)  and previous ubuntu versions but I'm all excited about the new Ubuntu 14.04 and hope that the drivers would work better and my laptop would stop behaving like a fan :)

Comment: i just found that! what setting should i use to install vista on?

Comment: You'll want FAT or FAT32, whichever works. Vista will change it to NTFS, I think.

Comment: i got further with the recovery disks to where it wants to choose the partition i created then it gives me an error shortly after starting :(